# Complicated PDO MYSQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, foreach

I've written a php function that allows you to update any entry in any table with any string values (one or multiple). PDO does not throw any errors, though the script does not seem to work! I've checked the name of the database, tables and fields multiple times. It's all correct. This is the only query in my functions that does not work. I believe it has something to do with the array im passing in to the SQL statement and the PDO->bindParam() function.

Code:

```
public function updateTableDetail($table, $id, $params) {

    include($this->doc_root . 'config/config.php');

    if (is_array($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            $param = Utilities::escapeString($param);
        }
    } else {
        throw new InvalidInputException(InputErrors::NOTANARRAY);
    }
    if (is_nan($id)) throw new InvalidInputException(InputErrors::NOTANUMBER);
    $table = Utilities::escapeString($table);

    $sql = "UPDATE " . $table . "
            SET " . $config['table_field_updated'] . " = :updated";
    while (current($params)) {
        $sql .= "," . key($params) . " = :" . key($params);
        next($params);
    }
    reset($params);
    $sql .= " WHERE id = :id 
             AND " . $config['userId'] . " = :userId";

    if ($this->serverConnector == null) {
        $this->serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
    }
    if ($this->db == null) {
        $this->db = $this->serverConnector->openConnectionOnUserDb($this->dbname);
    }
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $updated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $stmt->bindParam(':updated',$updated);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userId',$this->userId);
    while ($param = current($params)) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":".key($params),$param);
        next($params);
    }
    reset($params);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

EDIT: Don't worry about the include statement, the $config[]-array and the class-variables. It's all working aswell. Tested their values already.

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: Are you **SURE** that none of those dynamic parameters are duplicating `updated`, `id`, or `userID`? parameter names must be unique within the query. You've never bothered checking the return values of the bind calls and are just assuming they succeeded.

Comment: checking every bind-call is good practice? Thanks for your help, though Akam has already solved the problem

Comment: There are many flaws and vulnerabilities in this function

Comment: Getting those to disappear in all my class was just my next step :P No idea where to start though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part:

```
while ($param = current($params)) {
        $stmt->bindParam(":".key($params),$param);
        next($params);
    }
```

To:

```
foreach($params as $key => &value){
$stmt->bindParam(":$key",$value);
}
```

Because according to [PHP Manual: PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was use to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Comment: same in building the sql :)

Comment: Ok, you can accept it now :), I think `PDOStatement::bindValue()` might work for your method

Comment: who downvoted? I am sure that you are just that stranger that doing unethical downvotes!

Comment: Just wondered myself when I saw ya heaving 0 points though I upvoted .. o.O